# SQL ORACLE Grouping by all the days in a month

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

i have a table where there are two columns. One column is a timestamp, and the other one is labor hours quantity.

I need to obtain another month table, with two columns. One should be the day of the month, and the other the sum(labor) in that day.

Is easy i know, but the problem is that when there is a day without any labor, that row doesn´t appear. I need that row, with the day number and a zero as sum(labor)

Thanks for your help

the table i obtain now is

```
day  labor
1      8
2      4
3      7
4      3
6      7
7      9
```

and go on...

as you can see, the day 5 doesnt appear because this day there is no labor

I need taht day to appear like...5, Labor 0

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Do you want to do it only using sql or can you use pl/sql too?

Comment: i cant use pl/sql Guneli, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should *generate* days of date range (in example between 2014 and 2015) and then `left join` your labor stats, shcematic example:

```
--generating days
WITH days AS
 (SELECT DATE '2014-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 day1
    FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2015-01-01' - DATE '2014-01-01')

SELECT day.day1, NVL(sum(labor.labor),0) labot_sum FROM days
LEFT JOIN labor ON trunc(labor.timestamp_col) = days.day1
GROUP BY days.day1
```

**EDIT**

If you have integer days, generating should looks like

```
SELECT LEVEL day1 FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is to use `SUM(COALESCE(labor.labor, 0))` so that zero hours are returned for days with no labor as the OP requested. And I think you want `WITH days AS` instead of `WITH days OF YEAR`

Comment: but i only need one month each time. I only can select this range

Comment: @Madmartigan , so you should set month range

Comment: Great! @Madmartigan if my text help you, could accept the answer? ;) Thanks!

Comment: I have another issue with this problem. Now i have another column in the source table that indicate the zone (is a number 1,2,3,4,5,6). I have to group the labor in zones and days. When i do that, the days with no labor dont show.

Comment: @Madmartigan you can `CROSS JOIN` generated zones table to the query and  add zone to `LEFT JOIN` labor condition

Comment: Thanks @agent5566, but i don´t get it. Could you explain it a bit more?,I'll be very grateful. Thanks again.

Comment: something like this `with days as (SELECT LEVEL day1 FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365),
zones AS (SELECT LEVEL ZONE FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5)

SELECT days.day1, z.zone, NVL(sum(labor.labor),0) labot_sum FROM days
CROSS JOIN zones Z
LEFT JOIN labor ON trunc(labor.timestamp_col) = days.day1 AND z.zone = labor.zone
GROUP BY days.day1,z.zone`

Comment: Well, not at all...when I group by day is ok, but if i group by zone, it only sum the first day in each zone

Comment: SELECT 
     z.zona,
   NVL(sum(LABH),0) AS LABH
    
    FROM days CROSS JOIN zones Z left JOIN mega ON MEGA.fecha = days.day1 AND z.zona = mega.zona
    group by z.zona
    ORDER BY zona ASC

Comment: I can't, maybe could be for my oracle query

Comment: i dont know how to use sqlfiddle.com. Sorry

Comment: I got it @agent5566. I've made a subselect for the sum.